# get_meta_tags not working for same domain or origin

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, get-meta-tags

I am trying to use **get_meta_tags** function to fetch meta info of url. it is failed to give me meta info of url from same origin or domain.

like i am doing it from a controller http://example.com/fetch

```
$tags=get_meta_tags("http://example.com/blog/my-awesome-blog-post");
print_r($tags);
```

trying to get metainfo of  a page on my site http://example.com/blog/my-awesome-blog-post.
Sharing two screenshots:

**Dev instance error:**
[image: Dev error]

**Local Instance:**

[image: Local Image]

Getting error like **failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting. This is the error i am getting.**

I tried with different urls (Except facebook). I am getting successful results.

Is there anyway i can achieve this functionality.

Comment: **it is failed to give me meta info of url from same origin or domain.** how did you tried that ??

Comment: get_meta_tags is a PHP native function and not related to Codeigniter in anyway.

Comment: What tags do you have in the page generated by your URL? You can easily view them on your browser... Right Click - View Source or similar... and look at them.

Comment: Is there any error message involved?

Comment: failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting. This is the error i am getting.

Comment: Well then go figure out what redirects are happening, and why.

Comment: If you visit http://example.com/blog/my-awesome-blog-post in your browser does it show a redirect error?

Comment: No sir. It don't have any redirect issues. As far as i understand get_met_tags() Is sending a curl request internally. technically we should not curl same domain, that is where the redirects are happening i guess.

Comment: Try `var_dump( file_get_contents('http://example.com/blog/my-awesome-blog-post') );` to confirm you don't have any problems with your URL

Comment: I am testing it from my localhost. it is giving me exact results. but when i execute the code on my dev environment it is giving redirection issues.

Comment: So you are telling us that `file_get_contents()` on your localhost works but `file_get_contents()` on remote host doesn't? I have a guess that the problem is `https//` url you have in your error message. So if ssl is not enabled on you remote and enabled on your local  that can explin this behavior. You've mentioned that you tried different urls and some of them worked on your remote server ? were those url http? or https?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about your `localhost` but this is what I have deduced from your scenario.

Your website(or the page you are accessing) keep redirecting to a new URL every time PHP tries to access the url. When, the limit of max redirection i.e. 20 is reached PHP stops following and gives you the error.

This is happening because PHP request is a simple `http` request which is not handling any session/cookies values. So, Your website always treats it as a new request and keeps redirecting.

To verify, Please note that when you open your URL(`https://dev.kidengage.com/library`) in a incognito window it redirects you to `https://dev.kidengage.com/hyderabad` to set location for the user. And, after cookies are set, no more redirections takes place for the given URL.

This is where redirections are happening.

So, you need to fix this first or write a custom CURL script to fetch the data which can handle the session as well as redirections.

Hope it would help.

Comment: I observed this behavior. but why local host is working fine and why not the script, this question keeps poking me when i want to mess with my redirection.

Comment: @saikiran Yes. This is something you need to research as no other can have access to that.

Comment: @saikiran Please also check that if your localhost is also behaving in the same manner as of the dev url for `library` url.

Comment: @saikiran Maybe, it is because of additional `https` redirections which causes the limit reach as localhost is working on plane `http`. You can test it by using `file_get_contents` after increasing the `max_redirection_limit`

Comment: my localhost is a simple vanilla PHP project. to understand this better i need to know what get_meta_tags() is doing behind scenes. I am on it. let me know if you can get me any help in that.

Comment: @saikiran For functions like `fopen`, `file_get_contents`, `get_meta_tags` uses PHP wrappers for native protocols. It uses native `http:` protocol in case of your localhost and `https:` protocol  for your demo. These are some native PHP network protocols unlike curl which is a extension to php. For more information: [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php#wrappers), [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)